I have problems with creating a kaggle competition
I was trying hard to create a competition in Kaggle.
If I understand it correctly, I can upload a code somewhere at Kaggle (as a notebook) and than wait if someone was able to correct it so that the code behaves correctly.
Can someone direct me at the right buttons and places at Kaggle where I can do so?
